# Can't import the class of models from the python console in pycharm

Tags: python, class, model, console

Find the following error showed in [image: this image]

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Employee'"
```

Comment: Please give more information on what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

### I found the solution

Actually i just need to rerun the python console from pycharm